# Save contact form details in DB in a Play 1.2.5 app

Tags: playframework

I want to save the contact details of people who try to contact me on my website. I'm using temporarily in memory DB

Below is the code I'm using, which is giving me 
"Not found
POST /addContact" Error when I hit Submit.

Routes :

> GET     /                                       Application.index
>
> GET     /our-works                              Application.ourWorks
>
> GET     /contact-us                             Application.contactUs
>
> GET     /about-us                               Application.aboutUs
>
> GET     /plans                                 Application.plans
>
> POST   /contact-us             Application.addContact

Controller :

> public static void addContact(String name, String phone, String email, String query) {
>           Contact contact = new Contact();
>           contact.name = name;
>           contact.phone = phone;
>           contact.email = email;
>           contact.query = query;
>           contact.save();
>       }

Model :

> @Entity
>   public class Contact extends Model {

```
@Id
public String id;

public String name;

public String phone;

public String email;

public String query;
```

}

...
HTML Code:

`<form action="/addContact" method="post">`

Comment: Why do you have parameters for addContact in your controller?

Comment: I'm very new to Programming. Can you please help me out with the best way to go about this?

Comment: Well first off you don't have any routes that is "/addContact". I think it should be "/contact-us". Even if you correct that address route, Play will next nag you that you do not have addContact() method in your controller because you actually have addContact(String, String, String)

Comment: Thanks, buddy! After setting the correct route as "/contact-us", Its working now just fine with the addContact() method in controller that I wrote before :)

Comment: Hmm, weird. But glad it worked out.